# Trying to make a slope calculation work with SQL syntaxes

Tags: netezza

I'm a relatively new SQL programmer, I'm trying to make the below code work in SQL. The code is for calculating slopes for a given set of data, following the exact same logic as EXCEL SLOPE function. The problem right now is that count are not allowed since aggregations are being nested. But if I create a subquery for counts and sums, i would have to group on x and y, otherwise I wouldn't have x and y in my outer query to calculate on.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (X FLOAT, Y FLOAT);

INSERT INTO TEST (X, Y) VALUES (1,4.10242258729964);
INSERT INTO TEST (X, Y) VALUES (2,4.57708865242591);
INSERT INTO TEST (X, Y) VALUES (3,5.16785670619896);
INSERT INTO TEST (X, Y) VALUES (4,6.88149559336059);

select sum((x-sum(x)/count(x))^2)/sum(((x-sum(x)/count(x))*(y-sum(y)/count(y))))
from TEST
```

Comment: By the way, the database is Netezza, and I'm working in Aginity WorkBench, so a lot of your ordinary SQL commands might not work here... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a working version of the SQL you created:

```
SELECT sum((x-avgx)*(x-avgx)) / sum((x-avgx)*(y-avgy))
FROM TEST, (SELECT sum(X)/count(X) as avgx, sum(Y)/count(Y) as avgy FROM TEST) average;
```

I looked up the excel slope function and it is defined a bit differently:

```
SELECT sum((x-avgx)*(y-avgy)) / sum((x-avgx)*(x-avgx))
FROM TEST, 
    (
        SELECT 
            sum(X)/count(X) as avgx, 
            sum(Y)/count(Y) as avgy 
        FROM TEST
    ) average;
```

Hope this is what you needed :)

Comment: Just to note, your "Plan B" option comes back with the exact same result as the script I posted, also the script that "SQL Hacks" posted; but your "Plan A" option comes back with a very different answer indeed.  I think the OP might have had the Excel slope slightly awry?

Comment: TehSphinX, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I wanted to translate the formula that excel has defined for the slope function into a SQL calculation. I see that the catch is I can select things from different tables within the same query. Awesome answer, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the slope from sum(x * x) and sum(x * y) and avg(x) and avg(y) and n:

```
SELECT avg(x) AS mx,sum(x*x) AS sx2,sum(x*y) as sxy,avg(y) as my, count(x) AS n
FROM test
```

Then you can use:

```
SELECT (sxy-n*mx*my)/(sx2 - n* mx*mx)
FROM
(    SELECT avg(x) AS mx,sum(x*x) AS sx2,sum(x*y) as sxy,avg(y) as my, count(x) AS n
     FROM test
)
```

Comment: hi SQL Hacks, thank you so much for the answer. Could you please explain how your formula (sxy-n*mx*my)/(sx2 - n* mx*mx) accomplishes the same thing as my originally logic?

Comment: The formula is given in http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/calctopic1/regression.html... about halfway down the page, headed: Regression (Best Fit) Line

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something along these lines (I kept the syntax as simple as possible to avoid anything that might be problematic, like CTEs):

```
CREATE TABLE #test (x FLOAT, y FLOAT);
INSERT INTO #test SELECT 1, 4.10242258729964;
INSERT INTO #test SELECT 2, 4.57708865242591;
INSERT INTO #test SELECT 3, 5.16785670619896;
INSERT INTO #test SELECT 4, 6.88149559336059;
SELECT 
    (N * SUM_XY - SUM_X * SUM_Y) / (N * SUM_X2 - SUM_X * SUM_X) AS slope
FROM 
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS N,
        SUM(x) AS SUM_X,
        SUM(x * x) AS SUM_X2,
        SUM(y) AS SUM_Y,
        SUM(y * y) AS SUM_Y2,
        SUM(x * y) AS SUM_XY
    FROM
        #test) a;
```

Just ran this, then noticed you had another answer from "SQL Hacks".  I ran both versions and they get the exact same answer, but the other version is shorter :D